# Electric field due to infinite line of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, electric-current, gauss-law

In my textbook it derives the electric field due to an *infinitely* long linear charge using a cylindrical Gaussian surface. However, if I take a finite-length linear charge, and draw the same cylinder, I get the same field. Why does the derivation only work for an *infinitely* long linear charge?

Comment: The sentence beginning "By symmetry, the magnitude $E$..." is only true for an infinite cylinder, not for a finite one.

Comment: Still like if we apply the same formula on a finite linear charge won't the result be same considering that length of the linear charge and height of the cylinder will cancel each other out?

Comment: No. You can't apply it at all because the electric field isn't normal to the surface of the cylinder, and so $\int \vec E\cdot d\vec A\ne EA$.

Comment: Ok I get it. Is this the case same with a infinitely large plane whose electric field intensity is constant and it doesn't matter with radius but when we take a finite charged plane the electric field will not be normal to the surface of cylinder ?

Comment: Yes, that's the same.

Comment: See the result for finite length [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657861/evaluating-a-nasty-integral-that-mathematica-cant-deal-with/1657877#1657877)

Comment: @Chris:  That should be an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I suppose you're right. Added it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we cannot use Gauss's Law to find the Electric Field of a finite-length charged wire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24248/why-we-cannot-use-gausss-law-to-find-the-electric-field-of-a-finite-length-char)

Comment: I don't see why this was closed as a "homework-like question", though I agree that it's a duplicate of the one linked by @sammygerbil.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert More than one reason was given by the 5 of us voted to close the question. Only the majority reason is given to explain why the question has been put on hold. In the event of a tie the last vote cast is the decider. See [close vote reason logic when there isnt a majority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187300/)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in your textbook beginning "By symmetry, the magnitude E..." is only true for an infinite cylinder, not for a finite one. Generally speaking, it is impossible to get the electric field using only Gauss' law without some symmetry to simplify the final expression.

You can't apply Gauss' law in any useful way for a finite line charge, because the electric field isn't normal to the surface of the cylinder, and so $\int\vec E\cdot d\vec A\ne EA$.