# Why can't we use gauss's law to find the electric field passing along an axis perpendicular to the wire's midpoint?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I have seen this answer  [on why gauss's law can't be used to find the electric field due to a finite wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24248/)
however, I'm unable to understand why translational symmetry is lost if we're only concerned with the field along the axis perpendicular to the wire's midpoint.

Comment: I understand we require area to exploit guass's law basically, we could consider an infinitesimal area around the center , .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: in the finite wire case, there's an extra electric flux term due in the y-direction.

If you use Gauss's law,

$$\int E dS = Q/\epsilon_0$$

The integral term on the LHS involves the total electric flux contained within that imaginary cylinder.

In the case of the infinite wire, there was no flux in the y-direction since the wire runs continuous and we excluded that in our calculations.

However, in the finite wire case, we *must* include the flux term due to the electric field lines running in the y-direction. This is why calculating the electric field for a finite wire is more complex.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks a lot!